# PHP text to number or int

Tags: php

hello guys im new to this forum so i a little confused about giving the title ( and im sorry if this already asked somewhere i just dont know where to find it ) , i heard that returning string / text to mysql database is not that safe , so i just want to turn it into number , but i already search troughout google and cannot find what i was looking for , example i have text :

**"this is text within a quotes"**

i want to turn it into number or something like :

**"2421512152142152134"**

but what i got from php its returned **0** instead a number it was supposed to be : ( Screenshot )

[image: You can edit this word to anything u like , just don't break stackoverflow rules ;)]

i cannot find any method to do this , can anyone tell me what is the method to do it ?

i also want it work to all text like **utf-8** , **utf-7** ,  or something like that , not just listed text .

just a note , i hate decimal .

Comment: why you are converting string to int??

Comment: " i heard that returning string / text to mysql database is not that safe" don't know where you heard that, but okay. But do you really think by casting a string to int it will be more safe? A hacker could simply recast the int to a string. There's 0,0 gain in security. What you're trying just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You need to read some basic tutorials about how to store data to databases and the associated security risks. SQL injection prevention is not about changing strings to numbers, it is about escaping strings properly to prevent someone sending SQL statements to your database straight from the website.

Comment: Is 0 not a number? Technically it worked.

Comment: Twinfriends i don't sure a hacker can cast int to a string at variable inside proccess at the server , Markus Muller i want to turn it into number after escaping the string ....

Comment: @Albzi that is not the number i wanted ....

Comment: OK, so how did you come about that number you want it to be?

Comment: @Albzi , edited the question , i want the number is created based on the text , example is at question

Comment: @Sona i explained in the question ...

Comment: Yes but how are the numbers meant to correspond to the letter? a = 1, b = 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about why returning string / text to mysql database is not safe. Maybe if you have some SQL in that string, but in this case you need to escape your string to prevent it to be execute.
If you really want to transform your string for security reasons, i think some encryption / hash method can help you.

**hash() Example**

```
echo hash('ripemd160', 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
```

The above example will output:

```
ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3
```

Comment: thanks ! this is what i was looking for ( although have word inside it , its ok i don't care )  ! also mysql escape string make storing password become hard !

Comment: it's ok having word inside it , i can just turn it to number with some work

Answer (score 0):

This will never work due to restrictions of interger fields in Mysql-Database. It it is explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

In short words. If you like to parse a string like this "2421512152142152134" to an integer value, it fails, because the maximum number is 2147483647 or 4294967295 for unsigened integers.

You can try Bigint, but it is not safe, if you get long int or numbers.

Comment: thanks for the restrictions thing , didn't know it , but sorry cannot upvote due to downvote i received .